# Tomcat maxThreads change doesn't "catch"

Tags: tomcat

I have two connectors in my server.xml file:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" disableUploadTimeout="true" port="29171" />
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3" maxThreads="1" redirectPort="8443" port="29172" />
```

i added the maxThreads="1" but it seems i can still get multiple requests. i also tried setting a junk value (a string) but the service would still load and handle requests.

what am i doing wrong here?

thanks

**EDITED: attaching the thread dump**

```
2012-04-22 09:31:41 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
The following NLogHandler level was read - WARNING
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

2012-04-22 10:51:57 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized

2012-04-22 10:52:03 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
The following NLogHandler level was read - WARNING
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

2012-04-22 10:53:41 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized

2012-04-22 10:53:46 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized

2012-04-22 10:54:03 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
The following NLogHandler level was read - WARNING
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

2012-04-22 11:11:25 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
The following NLogHandler level was read - WARNING
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
2012-04-22 11:11:29
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.2-b06 mixed mode):

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0000000004ecb000 nid=0x34f4 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000004eb3000 nid=0x3348 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000428800 nid=0x25c4 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000426000 nid=0x3934 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000425000 nid=0x38b8 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x0000000000412000 nid=0x12e8 in Object.wait() [0x0000000004e5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e0c01300> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000e0c01300> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000000409000 nid=0x6a8 in Object.wait() [0x0000000004d5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e0c011d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00000000e0c011d8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=6 tid=0x00000000001dc800 nid=0x3890 runnable [0x000000000101d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at speechcat.externalinterfacecomm.MdalAccess.mdalInit(Native Method)
    at speechcat.externalinterfacecomm.ExternalInterfaceHandler.connect(ExternalInterfaceHandler.java:65)
    at speechcat.QueryEngine.load(QueryEngine.java:621)
    at speechcat.SpeechCat.loadSpeechCat(SpeechCat.java:4295)
    at localhost.axis.services.SpeechCat.SpeechCatSoapBindingImpl.init(SpeechCatSoapBindingImpl.java:48)
    - locked <0x000000009de54248> (a java.lang.Class for localhost.axis.services.SpeechCat.SpeechCatSoapBindingImpl)
    - locked <0x000000009de54248> (a java.lang.Class for localhost.axis.services.SpeechCat.SpeechCatSoapBindingImpl)
    at localhost.axis.services.SpeechCat.SpeechCatSoapBindingImpl.<clinit>(SpeechCatSoapBindingImpl.java:19)
    at localhost.axis.services.SpeechCat.SpeechCatWSConfig.contextInitialized(SpeechCatWSConfig.java:29)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    - locked <0x00000000e18152d0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    - locked <0x00000000e15e4c50> (a java.util.HashMap)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    - locked <0x00000000e15e4ba8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    - locked <0x00000000e15e4ba8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    - locked <0x00000000e1551a58> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    - locked <0x00000000e1551a58> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    - locked <0x00000000e1617c78> (a [Lorg.apache.catalina.Service;)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000000401800 nid=0x1ce4 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000000360800 nid=0x660 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=6 tid=0x0000000000362800 nid=0x3af8 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000004edc000 nid=0x3818 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1190

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 448000K, used 46336K [0x00000000e0c00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 384000K, 12% used [0x00000000e0c00000,0x00000000e39402e8,0x00000000f8300000)
  from space 64000K, 0% used [0x00000000fc180000,0x00000000fc180000,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 64000K, 0% used [0x00000000f8300000,0x00000000f8300000,0x00000000fc180000)
 PSOldGen        total 1024000K, used 0K [0x00000000a2400000, 0x00000000e0c00000, 0x00000000e0c00000)
  object space 1024000K, 0% used [0x00000000a2400000,0x00000000a2400000,0x00000000e0c00000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 17124K [0x000000009d200000, 0x000000009e6c0000, 0x00000000a2400000)
  object space 21248K, 80% used [0x000000009d200000,0x000000009e2b91d8,0x000000009e6c0000)
```

Comment: you can always get multiple requests. The requests would be queued and served one after the other using your one thread. Have you taken a thread dump to confirm you are spawning more then one worker thread?

Comment: OK, I got the following thread dump after setting maxThreads to 1, but i can't make out of it how many threads are running, what do u understand from it?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the maxThreads parameter, there is also acceptCount which is the size of the queued requests. I think default is 100. You may need to set it to 1 or 0. But what exactly you are trying to do/achieve here?